# Getting data from GitHub Archive

Tags: github-archive

I tried to get historical data from GitHub Archive by entering http://data.githubarchive.org/2012-04-15.json.gz, but I got no data.

How do I get data about activity on GitHub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the hour, sport.
[It is required](http://githubarchive.org).

Activity for April 11, 2012 at 3PM PST

```
data.githubarchive.org/2012-04-11-15.json.gz
```

Activity for April 11, 2012

```
data.githubarchive.org/2012-04-11-{0..23}.json.gz
```

Comment: @Steven Penny, did something change in the meantime? I get a `NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.` for `data.githubarchive.org/2012-04-11-{0..23}.json.gz`. The same for `data.githubarchive.org/2012-04-11-%7B0..23%7D.json.gz`.

Comment: That `{0..23}` syntax is for a shell like `bash` or `zsh` that will expand it in to 24 separate strings, like the `*` fileglob symbol. It's not a URL you can hit directly.